# from .pdftypes import PDFObjectNotFound ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFObjectNotFound'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert PDF to TEXT. But I have problem in PDFPage class. I have searched about it. But I didn't get anything and it gives me following error. I have also installed pdfminer.six for python 3.5 but still I didn't get any solution. Please help.

**Code :**

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
import os
import sys, getopt

#converts pdf, returns its text content as a string


 def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, 
                                      caching=True,
                                      check_extractable=True):
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams())
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text

            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/system/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfpage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .pdftypes import PDFObjectNotFound
ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFObjectNotFound'
```

Answer (score 6):

Uninstall `pdfminer3k` (if you have it installed)

```
$ pip uninstall pdfminer3k
```

and install `pdfminer.six` using the command below.

```
$ python -m pip install pdfminer.six
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in the beginning of your code and give it a shot:

```
from io import StringIO
```

Comment: It gives me error i.e. SyntaxError @Neal Titus Thomas

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 1
    from io import String.IO
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Sorry, It is StringIO not String.IO

Comment: Actually I have a problem with PDFPage. (from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage) It gives me error which I uploaded. What is the need of StringIO here?

Comment: I have already gone through it but still it does not work. It gives me the same error. I have been trying since 3 days but yet not done. Please help @Neal Titus Thomas